# Text of UILabel not showing up in view

Tags: ios, iphone, uilabel

I am creating some labels, but they do not appear. My code is this. May somebody help me out?

```
_scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
NSInteger numberOfViews = 3;

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++)
{

    CGFloat xOrigin;
    if (i == 0)
    {
        xOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;
    }
    else
    {
        xOrigin = i * (self.view.frame.origin.y+self.view.frame.size.width);
    }

   UIView *awesomeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
   awesomeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5/i green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1];

   UILabel *lbl1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
   [lbl1 setFrame:CGRectMake(30, 30, 200, 100)];
   lbl1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
   lbl1.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
   lbl1.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
   lbl1.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test Plan %d",i] ;
   [awesomeView addSubview:lbl1];


   [_scrollView addSubview:awesomeView];
```

Thanks

Comment: What's your view hierarchy? Where is this code placed?

Comment: Maybe _scrollView is nil?

Comment: atxe .. it is placed in a viewcontroller of the navigationcontroller after appdelegate

Comment: edzio .. no I can see the background colours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied your code and tried it out. I can see the label "Test Plan 0", but there is no way to use the pagination, because you did not set the `contentSize` property on your UIScrollView.

If you set `scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(scrollView.frame) * (i + 1), CGRectGetHeight(scrollView.frame));` you should the result of being able to paginate through your views.

Working example:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.window.bounds];
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    NSInteger numberOfViews = 3;

    for (int idx = 0; idx < numberOfViews; idx++)
    {
        CGRect awesomeViewFrame = self.window.frame;
        awesomeViewFrame.origin.x = idx * (CGRectGetMinX(self.window.frame) + CGRectGetWidth(self.window.frame));

        UIView *awesomeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:awesomeViewFrame];
        awesomeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5/idx green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1];

        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 30, 200, 100)];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        label.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test Plan %d", idx] ;
        [awesomeView addSubview:label];

        [scrollView addSubview:awesomeView];

        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(scrollView.frame) * (idx + 1), CGRectGetHeight(scrollView.frame));
    }


    [self.window addSubview:scrollView];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I am still not able to see that text on background view :(

Comment: Do you see your colored backgrounds on the 3 pages?

Comment: Have you seen your typo in `xOrigin = …`? Here you use `origin.y` instead `origin.x`...

Comment: yes .. but I add that label on view then I am able to see it but if i  put it in awesomeview .. then the problem occurs

Comment: Can you please
- tell us what `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(_scrollView.frame))` says?
- upload a screenshot
- provide a _complete_ failing example

Comment: it says {{0, 71}, {320, 52}}

Comment: Ok, your problem is very easy. Your label is centered vertically. It is 100pt high and starts at 30pt x. So you are only able to see the to 22pt of the label, where no text is present.

`UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 0, 200, 52)];`

If you use this coordinates for your label, you should properly see your text. If my answer solves your problem, please upvote it. :-)

Comment: My goodness .. how can I do such mistake .. Sascha .. thanks a ton .. I was wondering from half n hr .. why is this not showing up .. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49005/discussion-between-sascha-hameister-and-jean-luc-godard)